How to run on_success in Celery ONLY on the last worker process in a group?
I have been scratching my head about this for days now. I have a a background running task, which takes around 1 hour. I am processing 5000 images. I create a group of celery tasks and each task processes 1000 images each.
I have an on_success method where I create a 'Finished' database record, and remove the 'inProgress' record.
The problem however is, that even while having tons of checks in the on_success method, it still somehow generates 2 'Finished' database records. It sounds confusing, see the code below:
 def on_success(self, retval, task_id, *args, **kwargs):
        self.image_job.refresh_from_db()
        total_nr_of_images = self.image_job.total_nr_of_images
        stored_results = ImageJobResults.objects.filter(job=self.image_job).count()
        if stored_results == total_nr_of_images:
            #It means all the workers have completed processing images
            # for this job, and we need to create a csv file, and a Finished BC Job
            with transaction.atomic(using='my_db'):
                image_job = ImageJob.objects.select_for_update().get(id=self.image_job.id)
                if not ImageJobFinished.objects.filter(job=image_job).exists():
                    job_in_progress = ImageJobInProgress.objects.get(job=image_job)
                    started_at = job_in_progress.started_at
                    image_job.generate_results(started_at=started_at,completed_at=now(),csv_rds_handle_job_id=self.image_job.pk)
                    #Now that a ImageJobFinished is created.
                    # We delete the ImageJobInProgress instance
                    job_in_progress.delete()

        return super().on_success(retval, task_id, *args, **kwargs)

Now theoretically, the stored_results should be equal to total_nr_of_images only in the last worker. But both the workers somehow finish on the same time, and they get the same values here. Both of them then create the ImageJobFinished object, even though I check for existence of another object, it passes that check that. I just don't understand how this can be. It HAS to do with how the DB is accessed by both process i think.
I checked into celery chord, but that only helps inside a single view for small tasks i think.
